# I have a problem extracting data from firebase to react. This is a code im copying

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I have a problem with firebase when I try to connect from React. This is a code Im copying from youtube so its supposed work the same...

The idea is create a whatsapp version using email. The connection to send messages works fine but Im stuck in the extraction of the messages between users.

Here is the function that returns the message info:

```
const [messagesSnapshot] = useCollection(
        db
        .collection("chats")
        .doc(router.query.id)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp","asc")
       );

const showMessages = () => {  
        if(messagesSnapshot){ 
            return messagesSnapshot.docs.map( message => (         
                <Message 
                key={message.id} 
                user={message.data().user}
                message={{
                    ...message.data(),
                    timestamp: message.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime() 
                }}
                />
            ))
        } else {
            return JSON.parse(messages).map(message =>{
                <Message key={message.id} user={message.data().user} message={message}/>
            })
        }
    }
```

The database has a document called 'chats', with documents inside with users and another collection of 'messages' as [follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSVHn.png).

When the database gets the messages its supposed to print in a Menssage object.

```
function Message({user,message}){
    return (
        <Container>
            <p>ey</p>
            <p>{message.message}</p>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Am I missing something?

UPDATE:
All the code is this:

ChatScreen code(where it is supossed to show messages)

```
import { Avatar, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core"
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth"
import styled from "styled-components"
import { auth, db } from "../firebase"
import MoreVertIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MoreVert";
import AttachFileIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AttachFile";
import { useCollection } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore"
import InsertEmoticonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/InsertEmoticon"
import MicIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mic"
import Message from "./Message"
import { useState } from "react"
import firebase from "firebase"

function ChatScreen({chat, messages}) {
    const[user]=useAuthState(auth);
    const[input, setInput] = useState("");
    const router = useRouter();
    const [messagesSnapshot] = useCollection(
        db
        .collection("chats")
        .doc(router.query.id)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp","asc")
       );

    const showMessages = () => {  
        if(true){ 
            return messagesSnapshot.docs.map( message => (         
                <Message 
                key={message.id} 
                user={message.data().user}
                message={{
                    ...message.data(),
                    timestamp: message.data().timestamp?.toDate().getTime() 
                }}
                />
            ))
        } else {
            return JSON.parse(messages).map(message =>{
                <Message key={message.id} user={message.data().user} message={message}/>
            })
        }
    }

    const sendMessage = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();

        //Actualizar la ultima vez vista
        db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).set(
            {
                lastSeen: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
            }, 
            { merge: true}
        );
    
        db.collection("chats").doc(router.query.id).collection("messages").add({
            timeStamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            message: input,
            user:user.email,
            photoURL: user.photoURL
        });

        setInput("");
    }

    return (
        <Container>
            <Header>
                <Avatar />

                <HeaderInformation>
                    <h3>Email receptor</h3>
                    <p>Última vez conectado</p>
                </HeaderInformation>
                <HeaderIcons>
                    <IconButton>
                        <AttachFileIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                    <IconButton>
                        <MoreVertIcon/>
                    </IconButton>
                </HeaderIcons>
            </Header>

            <MessageContainer>
                {showMessages()}
                <EndOfMessage/> 
            </MessageContainer>

            <InputContainer>
                <InsertEmoticonIcon/>
                <Input value={input} onChange={ (e) => setInput(e.target.value)} />
                    <button hidden disabled={!input} type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>
                        Enviar mensaje
                    </button>
                <MicIcon/>
            </InputContainer>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default ChatScreen;

const Container = styled.div ``;

const Input = styled.input `
    flex:1;
    outline:0;
    border:none;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    padding:20px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
`;

const InputContainer = styled.form `
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    padding:10px;
    position:sticky;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:white;
    z-index:100;
`;

const Header = styled.div `
    position: sticky;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    padding: 11px;
    height: 80px;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
`;

const HeaderInformation = styled.div `
    margin-left: 15px;
    flex: 1;

    > h3{
        margin-bottom:  3px;
    }

    > p {
        font-size:14px;
        color: gray;
    }
`;

const EndOfMessage = styled.div ``;

const HeaderIcons = styled.div ``;

const MessageContainer = styled.div `
    padding:30px;
    background-color:#e5dedB;
    min-height:90vh;
`;
```

And message component:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

function Message({user,message}){
    return (
        <Container>
            <p>{message.message}</p>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Message;

const Container = styled.div ``
```

Comment: What is the issue? Is your component calling `showMessages`?

Comment: yeah, after that code there is call to this function. The problem is that the messages are not shown. It looks like the if condition its not working properly (its is supposed to get an array with all the messages)

Comment: Can you show how this `showMessages` is called? What is `messages`? Can yo update your question to include all relevant code? Can we see this entire component that is using the hook and trying to render messages?